# IsNull with Equal ¿What does this means?

Tags: sql-server

I have a basic question of SQL

What does the IsNull()=0 means in this code?
As far as I know, = assigns a value, but in this case it is used inside a Where statement.
Hope somebody can explain it to me :)

```
    Where       vol.espe_codigo =   matriz.espe_codigo
    And         IsNull(costo_gerencias.plde_codigo,0)   =   0
```

Comment: Did you google "SQL Server ISNULL"?

Comment: `ISNULL( expression, alternative_value )`

Comment: You should read up a bit on `WHERE` clauses. `=` does not mean assignment in a `WHERE` clause, it is checking for equality.  This is extremely basic, and nearly every tutorial online that you could stumble upon will explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if `costo_gerencias.plde_codigo` is null, it will return `0` or whatever the second argument is to the `ISNULL` function.  In this case, the `WHERE` clause is basically saying "where `vol.espe_codigo` is equal to `matriz.espe_codigo` and `costo_gerencias.plde_codigo` is null or equal to zero."

Comment: Not entirely true.  You would need to check if `(plde_codigo is null OR plde_codigo = 0)`. It seems like the data could be null or 0 and they want records which are Null or 0.  not just those that are null.

Answer (score 3):

isnull(firstvalue, secondvalue) tests if the value for firstvalue is NULL or not. When the value is not null than this value is returned, but when the value is null than the value of secondvalue is returned.

Examples :

```
declare @test varchar(100) = 'abc'
declare @test2 varchar(100) = '123'

isnull(@test, @test2) will return 'abc'
```

second example :

```
declare @test varchar(100) = null
declare @test2 varchar(100) = '123'

isnull(@test, @test2) will return '123'
```

third example :

```
declare @test varchar(100) = ''
declare @test2 varchar(100) = '123'

isnull(@test, @test2) will return ''
```

I use it most to check on varchar columns, since they may contain an empty string which is not the same as NULL, but in a DataGridView or TextBox you cannot see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

[`IsNull()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) is a function which takes two input values of any type; however the second must be implicitly convertible to the type to the 1st parameter. (See link)

The database engine evaluates the first parameter and if it's null, the system returns the second parameter. If the 1st parameter is not null, it returns the value of the first parameter.

So in your case the engine will return the value 0 if plde_codigo is null. If not null it returns the value of plde_codigo passed in.

This in turn means your result set will only contain records which have a NULL or 0 value in plde_Codigo; in addition to other limiting criteria.

It could also be written as:

`(costo_gerencias.plde_codigo is NULL OR costo_gerencias.plde_codigo =   0)`

or to be more database agnostic:

`coalesce(costo_gerencias.plde_codigo,0)=0`

But in this case plde_codigo must be numeric; whereas it could be text when using `isNull()`