# IsNull with Equal inside of a FROM/JOIN Statement "isNull(t.fieldname,'N') = 'Y'"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hey guys I'm somewhat new here so I hope I do this properly I apologize if i dont.

Anyway I am trying to understand this `isNull` operator in SQL. I completely understand the fact that `isnull` checks if the field in the 1st argument is a `Null` value then replaces that `Null` with the second value.

However what does the equal sign outside of the `ISNULL` operator mean here(`= 'Y'`)?

I don't understand how this equal sign will apply to what I already know about `ISNULL()`. Btw this `isNull` statement was in a `FROM` statement more specifically a `JOIN`. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. The syntax for the `ISNULL()` is below. Thanks in advance!

`isNull(t.fieldname,'N') = 'Y'`

Comment: First of all, this is a *bad* idea. Applying a function on a field prevents the server from using indexes. `ISNULL()` will return the first non-null argument. This expression will replace `NULL` with `N` but then compare it with `Y`. The equivalent would be `t.FieldName = 'Y'`, produce the *same* result and not harm performance

Comment: I kinda just learned or grasped this concept today with you guys's help. However I do agree, the statement seems like its going in a roundabout way to achieve something so simple. Seeing that made me think that there was some kind of understanding of ISNULL and the equal sign that I just couldn't seem to rap my head around. However I didn't write the code, just editing it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is equivalent to :

```
(t.fieldname IS NOT NULL AND t.fieldname = 'Y')
```

However, this would simplify with this also :

```
t.fieldname = 'Y'
```

This would filtered only records which has `fieldname` = 'Y'. This assumes that parts comes from `WHERE` clause, if not might be for `JOIN` with `ON` clause then you can write a simple `case` expression instead :

```
ON (CASE WHEN t.FieldName IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE t.Fieldname END) = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was speculating around it being something of that sort but you hit the nail right on the head. Appreciate the help.

Comment: It's *not* equivalent. The first form is SARGable while `ISNULL(fieldName,'N') = 'Y'` isn't.

Comment: The equivalent expression is `'Y' = CASE WHEN t.FieldName is NULL THEN 'N' ELSE t.Fieldname END` and is as ugly as it looks

Comment: Minor nitpick - even the `CASE` expression isn't *necessarily* equivalent if the type of `FieldName` is of lower precedence than the `(n)(var)char` types, since the `ISNULL` will convert down instead of up. E.g. if `FieldName` is `varbinary(5)`, then `'N'` ought to be cast to that in the `CASE` expression too. Because `ISNULL` doesn't follow normal precedence rules.

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL is a function that simply replaces the NULL values with the specified value, otherwise returns with the original value.

In your case `isNull(t.fieldname,'N')` returns back with `N` if the `t.fieldname is null`

for examples you could check this page: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat similar case being discussed here. 
[IsNull with Equal ¿What does this means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348318/isnull-with-equal-what-does-this-means)

I hope that it can help you.

Comment: Yes i have already checked that thread. However I didnt find any of the explanations clear at pertaining to my issue.

Comment: Yeah that person had more of a problem understanding how an Equal sign operates in a WHERE statement than with the actual ISNULL() operator.

Comment: Yeah okay. Maybe i didn't understand the question properly (-: